# 2004 Volkswagen New Beetle oil pan replacement: stuck bolt

Tags: vw, stuck-bolt, oil-pan

I’m trying to replace the oil pan on my 2004 Volkswagen New Beetle Turbo S. (My best guess is I hit a speed bump too fast or too hard. It’s cracked.) I’ve gotten every bolt out after draining the oil, but one bolt won’t come out. It’s stripped down on the inside from my attempts with an Alan key, and I can’t get a 10mm socket around it due to the weird angle. I’m at my wit’s end here, how might I go about getting the bolt off?

Comment: A photo of the bolt will help a lot.

Comment: Search for screw extractors. Whether internal or external, they're designed with a very coarse set of tapered, hardened  cutting edges to screw into or onto stripped areas, grab and tighten as the extractor is turned ccw. Worse case scenario is the bit won't fit and drilling into a bolt will allow a bit to bite for better extraction.